# Pause/Play button listener

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I've been doing a lot of research regarding this matter and I cannot seem to get this code to detect when the play/pause button is pressed on a headset. I currently have my code listening to the volume buttons being pressed to which outputs an action to my application perfectly fine.

The problem I am facing is there is no mp3 or multimedia incorporated into my application, so pretty much I just need the app to detect when the physical play/pause button is pressed.

I reviewed http://www.sagorin.org/ios-playing-audio-in-background-audio/ , to which I was unsuccessful due to no multimedia being detected inside the application. I also attempted to do a first responder function to no luck.

any ideas or if someone had a similar problem, this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: "I also attempted to do a first responder function to no luck." Show what you did, please.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the [Remote Control-segment of the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Remote-ControlEvents/Remote-ControlEvents.html). Three criterias need to be met to be notified of the button press on the headset:

- Be the first responder. The view or view controller that presents the multimedia content must be the first responder.
- Turn on the delivery of remote control events. Your app must explicitly request to begin receiving remote control events.
- Begin playing audio. Your app must be the “Now Playing” app. Restated, even if your app is the first responder and you have turned on event delivery, your app does not receive remote control events until it begins playing audio.

Once you've met these requirements, you can start coding. From the documentation:

> Listing 5-1  Preparing to receive remote control events
>
> ```
> - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
>     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
>
>     // Turn on remote control event delivery
>     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
>
>     // Set itself as the first responder
>     [self becomeFirstResponder];
> }
> ```
>
> When the view or view controller is no longer managing audio or video,
>   it should turn off the delivery of remote control events. It should
>   also resign first-responder status in the viewWillDisappear: method,
>   as shown in Listing 5-2.
>
> Listing 5-2  Ending the receipt of remote control events
>
> ```
> - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
>
>     // Turn off remote control event delivery
>     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
>
>     // Resign as first responder
>     [self resignFirstResponder];
>
>     [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
> }
> ```
>
> Handling Remote Control Events
>
> To handle remote control events, the first responder must implement
>   the remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: method declared by UIResponder.
>   The method implementation should evaluate the subtype of each UIEvent
>   object passed in and then, based on the subtype, send the appropriate
>   message to the object that presents the audio or video content.
>   Listing 5-3 sends play, pause, and stop messages to an audio object.
>   Other remote control UIEvent subtypes are possible, see UIEvent Class
>   Reference for details.
>
> Listing 5-3  Handling remote control events
>
> ```
> - (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)receivedEvent {
>
>     if (receivedEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {
>
>         switch (receivedEvent.subtype) {
>
>             case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
>                 [self playOrStop: nil];
>                 break;
>
>             case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack:
>                 [self previousTrack: nil];
>                 break;
>
>             case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:
>                 [self nextTrack: nil];
>                 break;
>
>             default:
>                 break;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```